# C structures — problem entering more than one string

Tags: c

I am trying to add more than one string to a string in a struct and when I get to the line "fgets" the program just crashes/closes.  If someone knows what the problem is in my code, I will very much appreciate that.

I was debugging the code and the problem is in the function **"addReason"** in the line of **"fgets"** but I didn't understand what exactly the problem.

My code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define PRO_OP 1
#define CON_OP 2
#define PRINT_OP 3
#define EXIT_OP 4

#define STR_LEN 50
#define MAX_LIST_LENGTH 10

typedef struct reasonList
{
    char* listName;
    char* reasons[MAX_LIST_LENGTH];
    int numReasons;
} reasonList;


void initList(reasonList* list, char* name);
void addReason(reasonList* list);
void printList(reasonList* list);
int menu(void);
void myFgets(char str[], int n);
void deleteList(reasonList* list);

int main(void)
{
    char dilemma[STR_LEN] = { 0 };
    int op = 0;
    reasonList proList;
    initList(&proList, "PRO");
    reasonList conList;
    initList(&conList, "CON");
    printf("What is your dilemma?\n");
    myFgets(dilemma, STR_LEN);
    while (op != EXIT_OP)
    {
        op = menu();

        switch (op)
        {
            case(PRO_OP):
                addReason(&proList);
                break;
            case(CON_OP):
                addReason(&conList);
                break;
            case(PRINT_OP):
                printf("Your dilemma:\n");
                printf("%s\n\n", dilemma);

                printList(&proList);
                printList(&conList);
                break;
            case(EXIT_OP):
                deleteList(&proList);
                deleteList(&conList);
                break;
        }
    }
    printf("Good luck!\n");
    getchar();
    return 0;
}
/*
Function will add a reason to the list
input: the list to add to and its name
output: none
*/
void addReason(reasonList* list)
{
    printf("Enter a resone to add to list %s:\n", list->listName);
    fgets(list->reasons[list->numReasons], STR_LEN, stdin);
    list->reasons[strcspn(list->reasons[list->numReasons], '\n')] = '\0';
    list->numReasons++;
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  Please read about how to create an MCVE ([Minimal, Complete, Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)
 — or MRE or whatever name SO now uses)
or an
SSCCE ([Short, Self-Contained, Correct Example](http://sscce.org/))
 — the same idea by a different name.  You show quite a lot of code that is not relevant.

Answer (score 2):

You have to allocate buffer and assign that before reading strings.

```
void addReason(reasonList* list)
{
    printf("Enter a resone to add to list %s:\n", list->listName);
    list->reasons[list->numReasons] = malloc(STR_LEN); /* allocate buffer */
    if (list->reasons[list->numReasons] == NULL) return; /* check if allocation succeeded */
    fgets(list->reasons[list->numReasons], STR_LEN, stdin);
    list->reasons[strcspn(list->reasons[list->numReasons], '\n')] = '\0';
    list->numReasons++;
}
```