# C error reading characters of string. tring to print from string without success

Tags: c, struct, dynamic-memory-allocation, c-strings, fgets

I am writing a code and i need to get strings from "addReasons" function and print all the strings I got in other function and I get Runtime error that says "error reading characters of string" if someone can tell me how to fix that it will be very helpful. Thank you.

Calling the function like that:

```
addReasons(&proList);
addReasons(&conList);
printList(proList);
printList(conList);
```

The code:

```
typedef struct reasonList
{
    char* listName;
    char* reasons[MAX_LIST_LENGTH];
    int numReasons;
} reasonList;

/*
Function will add a reason to the list
input: the list to add to and its name
output: none
*/
void addReason(reasonList* list)
{
    int index = 0;
    index = list->numReasons;
    if (index < MAX_LIST_LENGTH)
    {
        printf("Enter a reason to add to list %s: ", list->listName);
        fgets(&list->reasons[index], STR_LEN, stdin);
        list->numReasons++;
    }
}
/*
Function will print a list of reasons
input: the list
output: none
*/
void printList(reasonList list)
{
    int i = 0;
    printf("List %s\n", list.listName);
    printf("---------\n");
    for (i = 0; i < list.numReasons; i++)
    {
        printf("%s\n", list.reasons[i]);
    }
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [C structures — problem entering more than one string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67301860/c-structures-problem-entering-more-than-one-string)

Answer (score 1):

`fgets` expects a `char*` argument, but you pass a `char**` argument. The compiler warns about that:

```
warning: incompatible pointer types passing 'char **' to parameter of type 'char *';
remove & [-Wincompatible-pointer-types]
   fgets(&list->reasons[index], STR_LEN, stdin);
         ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

The correct way would be:

```
    fgets(list->reasons[index], STR_LEN, stdin);
```

However, now that would use an uninitialized pointer. So you need to allocate the memory for that string first and initialize the pointer with the address of that:

```
    list->reasons[index] = malloc(STR_LEN);
    fgets(list->reasons[index], STR_LEN, stdin);
```

You'll also need to `free()` that memory later when you're done with it, or else you'll leak that memory if your program is long-running.

Answer (score 0):

The data member `reasons` of the structure `reasonList` is an array of pointers of the type `char *`.

```
char* reasons[MAX_LIST_LENGTH];
```

So the first argument of this call of `fgets`

```
fgets(&list->reasons[index], STR_LEN, stdin);
```

has the type `char **` while the function expects an argument of the type `char *`. So this call invokes undefined behavior.

Also from the presented code it is unclear whether these pointers (elements of the array) point to character arrays. If you did not allocate dynamically character arrays to which the pointers will point then if you will even write correctly

```
fgets( list->reasons[index], STR_LEN, stdin);
```

nevertheless such a call again will invoke undefined behavior.

Taking into account the error message it seems you indeed forgot to allocate character arrays that would be pointed to by the elements (pointers) of the array.

Take into account that the function `fgets` can append the new line character `'\n'` to  entered strings that you should remove.

The function could look for example the following way

```
int addReason( reasonList *list )
{
    int success = list->numReasons < MAX_LIST_LENGTH;
 
    if ( success )
    {
        list->reasons[list->numReasons] = malloc( STR_LEN );
        success = list->reasons[list->numReasons] != NULL;

        if ( success )
        {
            list->reasons[list->numReasons][0] = '\0';

            printf( "Enter a reason to add to list %s: ", list->listName );
            if ( fgets( list->reasons[list->numReasons], STR_LEN, stdin ) != NULL )
            {
                list->reasons[list->numReasons][ strcspn( list->reasons[list->numReasons], "\n" ) ] = '\0';
            }
            
            ++list->numReasons;
        }
    }

    return success;
}
```

Another reason of the problem can be related to the data member `listName` that you should either assign with a string literal or again you need to allocate dynamically a character array that will be pointed to by the data member.

By the way the function `printList` should be declared like

```
void printList( const reasonList *list );
```

instead of

```
void printList( const reasonList *list );
```

because it is inefficient to create a copy of an object of the type struct `reasonList` instead of passing a pointer to it.

Here is a demonstrative program.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define MAX_LIST_LENGTH 10
#define STR_LEN 50

typedef struct reasonList
{
    char* listName;
    char* reasons[MAX_LIST_LENGTH];
    int numReasons;
} reasonList;

int addReason( reasonList *list )
{
    int success = list->numReasons < MAX_LIST_LENGTH;
 
    if ( success )
    {
        list->reasons[list->numReasons] = malloc( STR_LEN );
        success = list->reasons[list->numReasons] != NULL;

        if ( success )
        {
            list->reasons[list->numReasons][0] = '\0';

            printf( "Enter a reason to add to list %s: ", list->listName );
            if ( fgets( list->reasons[list->numReasons], STR_LEN, stdin ) != NULL )
            {
                list->reasons[list->numReasons][ strcspn( list->reasons[list->numReasons], "\n" ) ] = '\0';
            }
            
            ++list->numReasons;
        }
    }

    return success;
}

void printList( const reasonList *list )
{
    printf( "List %s\n", list->listName);
    printf("---------\n");
    for ( int i = 0; i < list->numReasons; i++ )
    {
        printf( "%s\n", list->reasons[i] );
    }
}

int main(void) 
{
    reasonList list = { .listName = "List of reasons", .numReasons = 0 };
    
    addReason( &list );
    
    printList( &list );
    
    return 0;
}
```

The program output might look like

```
Enter a reason to add to list List of reasons: Unallocated memory
List List of reasons
---------
Unallocated memory
```

If you will allocate memory for reasons dynamically then you should free all allocated memory before exiting the program.